# MySQL Timestamp and NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

We are on MYSQL 5.7 and when we create  a column like so in our DDL

```
my_update_timestamp timestamp(6) NOT NULL
```

MySQL complains when we try to create the table with

```
Error 1067: Invalid default value for my_update_timestamp.
```

Is it possible to have a not nullable timestamp with no default value?

Comment: How are you trying to insert new values?

Comment: This is not at insert time, this is at table creation time: I cannot create the table

Comment: You should be able: [rextester](http://rextester.com/IYZSI60825), [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c5c8a9bcc78a0856a694a1d33a99e7b3)

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860351/mysql-column-type-timestamp-implicitly-includes-not-null-default-current-time

Comment: Timestamp has a specific function in Mysql. "track changes in record"  By default, field creation should contain default and on update function. If you are looking just a datetime field then use datetime type.

Answer (score 1):

The usual mistake is to not include `(6)` on the default:

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```

See about 3/4 of the way down on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html .

Also, consider that to set this to:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

Comment: I do not want to provide a default, why should I ? :D

Comment: What is the value of `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`?  (I added a link to my Answer.)